# on overflow of parent div the child div is not visible out of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<section class="margin-top-30">
            <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="lightbgblock" style="overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:scroll;">
                        <h3>
                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i> Categories
                        </h3>
                        <section>
                            <h5
                                style="background-color: orange; padding-left: 10px; border-radius: 20px; line-height: inherit;">
                                <strong>Private Events</strong>
                            </h5>
                            <ul id="private_events_list" class="listing_categories">
                                <li><a href="#" class="wedding_icon">Wedding</a>
                                    <div class="list_sub_categories container">
                                        <div class="row col-lg-12 col-xs-12">

                                            <table>
                                                <tr class="container">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <ul class="list-group col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                                                            <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label
                                                                class="checkbox-inline"><input
                                                                    class="checkbox-input checkByDef" type="checkbox">Marriage
                                                                    Halls/Kalyana Mandapams</label></li>
                                                            <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label
                                                                class="checkbox-inline"><input
                                                                    class="checkbox-input checkByDef" type="checkbox" />Organizers</label></li>
```

The above is the section of code the ul's and li's both the parent and child lists.
The first image is actually what i want. i.e on mouse hover over the parent list , the child list should be visible.
But the second image is what actually i am getting, the child div is not visible out of the parent div which i need to make it visible as in first image.

[[image: [2][[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKRge.png)

Comment: can you post your code with in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pavanprabhu29/L5g7edhz/

Comment: hello can anyone help me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L5g7edhz/1/ see the updated fiddle are need like this

Comment: Change the first line  `min-width` instead of `min-height` like this `<section class="margin-top-30;" style="overflow:auto;min-width:200px;">`

Comment: The scroll is visible at the right most position of the page which i don't need it such a way. I just need the scroll beside the parent list and the child list should be displayed on hover but above the scrolls

Comment: One more thing to be noted is , The scroll should be shown for the main list but not the section. Section already has other contents besides this lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself. I just made the child list div static and added overflow: auto to the parent div. Which enables the scrolls of parent div and as the child div is positioned as static it would be in same position and will be show anyway.

Thankyou @prasad for your responses.